# "Waiting for samples..." message in perfmon report while running JMeter

Tags: jmeter, perfmon

I am getting "Waiting for samples..." in *perfmon* report while running the script in JMeter.

The agent server is run correctly and the application itself runs correctly.

[image: perfmon screenshot]

I am expecting the graph to be loaded correctly in the report.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file, either click the icon with yellow exclamation mark or open the log file with your favourite text viewer, it will tell you where the problem is so you could resolve it.

[image]

Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) article just in case to double check that everything is "set up correctly"